# HTTP code range check in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, http, httpresponse

I want to be able to do the following in Ruby:

I can only describe what I need to do in PHP code as of now:

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$httpResponse = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpResponse >= 200 && $httpResponse < 300 || $httpResponse == 302) {
     do some action;
}
```

I know about [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) which I got the following code from:

```
require 'net/http'

def check_status(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose a better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri_str))

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then #if 200 then do action
    puts "It works!"
    response.code
    #response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then #if 3xx then check where it goes
    location = response['location']
    check_status(location, limit - 1)
  else
    response.value
  end
end

print check_status('https://git.company.com')
```

But I'm not sure how to check if the HTTP response is `>= 200` and `< 300` or `302`.

Do I have to write a check for all of the [HTTP responses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTP+Response+Classes)? Or is there an easier way like that PHP code above?

Comment: Why not just test `response.code` directly if that's all you care about?

Comment: I think because my brain is fried. :(  Idk why I didn't think of that. I'm the one who added that response.code too.. lol

Comment: If you can fix your code, maybe you can answer your own question to help others stuck in the same situation.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm doing that as we speak.. :D

Comment: Don't limit yourself to using Net::HTTP. Ruby has many HTTP clients so find one that fits your way of thinking. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients Net::HTTP is there to act as a low-level  building block, most often used to build new clients that aren't implemented elsewhere. Using the prebuilt wheel can save you a lot of code and debugging time.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question, but I am facing a new small problem now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so thanks to [tadman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709821/http-code-range-check-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment66717485_39709821) (for pointing out my obvious mistake.. xD) and for [the Tin Man's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709821/http-code-range-check-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment66717658_39709821), I've changed the code to the following and it works as expected

```
require 'rest-client'

def check_status(uri_str)

    response = RestClient.get "#{uri_str}"

    case response.code
    when 200...300 || 302
        puts "It works!"
    else
        puts "It doesn't work!"
        puts "#{response.code}"
    end
end

print check_status('https://git.company.com')
```

NOTE: You will need to have the [rest-client](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/rest-client) gem installed, by doing: `gem install rest-client`